# React-native Writing Pdf files Using React-Native-fs (IOS)

Tags: ios, react-native, react-native-fs

Need to write a file(pdf) and store it in device memory. I'm using react-native-fs library.

I want to make users able to read this file using iBooks as well.

These are react-native-fs 's constants

- MainBundlePath (String) The absolute path to the main bundle
  directory
- CachesDirectoryPath (String) The absolute path to the    caches
  directory
- DocumentDirectoryPath (String) The absolute path to    the document
  directory
- TemporaryDirectoryPath (String) The absolute    path to the temporary
  directory (iOS only)

this is my download code

```
  RNFS.downloadFile({
      fromUrl: fileLink,          
      toFile: RNFS.MainBundlePath + '/' + fileName
    }).promise.then((dwResult) => {

      console.log(dwResult.jobId + 'jobid');
      return true
    }).catch((err) => {

      alert(err);
      return false
    })
  }
```

What do I have to assign toFile so that written file can be seen using iBooks.
Note: I'm able to write file app's path using DocumentDirectoryPath.

Answer (score 2):

There're some restrictions on iOS so you may not be able to open a file directly using iBooks. However, latest beta version of [react-native-fetch-blob](https://github.com/wkh237/react-native-fetch-blob/issues/108) has an API which displays an option menu and let user decide how to deal with the file.

[image]

Alternatively, you can directly preview the file with default document viewer, there's also a `Share Button` for display the option menu

[image]

An example for download and open a PDF file with `react-native-fetch-blob`

```
  RNFetchBlob.config({
    fileCache : true,
    appendExt : 'pdf'
  })
  .fetch('GET',`${TEST_SERVER_URL}/public/book.pdf`)
  .then((res) => {
    // open the document directly
    RNFetchBlob.ios.previewDocument(res.path())
    // or show options
    // RNFetchBlob.ios.openDocument(res.path())
  })
```

Comment: You mean if i write or download a file using my application, i can't preview it using ibooks or something. I want to preview them when my app is closed. İsn't that possible?